# Adafruit eInk Display and ESP32 Huzzah

Tags: arduino, esp32, e-ink

I have an [ESP32 Huzzah](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah32-esp32-feather/overview) board from Adafruit and am trying to control a [2.19" flexible eInk display](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4262) to no avail. While the screen occasionally updates, the full black and white "clear" screens work but then the image is either incoherent lines (makes me think a potential data issue) or garbled static.

The main issue I'm seeing is also that I cannot reliably update the screen. After waiting the necessary 2-3 minutes to hit reset on the uC the screen rarely updates. I cannot seem to reliably force this change and therefore can't reasonably test different code/hardware configs.

So far I've tried:

- Checking the electrical connections with a multi-meter
- a new eInk display
- a new eInk Friend driver
- a new ESP 32
- different pins for chip selects
- different pins for Reset line (both parallel w/ uC and GPIO)
- adding/removing the Busy line (uses time delay w/o)

Has anyone else successfully controlled such a display with a 3V3 signal/power? I've included images and my code below as well.

[image: ESP32 Huzzah]
[image: eInk Friend Driver Board]
[image: eInk Display with Lines]

```
/***************************************************
  Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code,
  please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing
  products from Adafruit!

  Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada for Adafruit Industries.
  MIT license, all text above must be included in any redistribution
 ****************************************************/

#include "Adafruit_EPD.h"


#define EPD_CS      4
#define EPD_DC      36
#define SRAM_CS     39

#define EPD_RESET   -1 // can set to -1 and share with microcontroller Reset!
#define EPD_BUSY    -1 // can set to -1 to not use a pin (will wait a fixed delay)

/* Uncomment the following line if you are using 1.54" tricolor EPD */
//Adafruit_IL0373 display(152, 152, EPD_DC, EPD_RESET, EPD_CS, SRAM_CS, EPD_BUSY);

/* Uncomment the following line if you are using 1.54" monochrome EPD */
//Adafruit_SSD1608 display(200, 200, EPD_DC, EPD_RESET, EPD_CS, SRAM_CS, EPD_BUSY);

/* Uncomment the following line if you are using 2.13" tricolor EPD */
//Adafruit_IL0373 display(212, 104, EPD_DC, EPD_RESET, EPD_CS, SRAM_CS, EPD_BUSY);
Adafruit_IL0373 display(250,122, EPD_DC, EPD_RESET, EPD_CS, SRAM_CS, EPD_BUSY);
#define FLEXIBLE_213

/* Uncomment the following line if you are using 2.13" monochrome 250*122 EPD */
//Adafruit_SSD1675 display(250, 122, EPD_DC, EPD_RESET, EPD_CS, SRAM_CS, EPD_BUSY);

/* Uncomment the following line if you are using 2.7" tricolor or grayscale EPD */
//Adafruit_IL91874 display(264, 176, EPD_DC, EPD_RESET, EPD_CS, SRAM_CS);

/* Uncomment the following line if you are using 2.9" EPD */
//Adafruit_IL0373 display(296, 128, EPD_DC, EPD_RESET, EPD_CS, SRAM_CS, EPD_BUSY);
//#define FLEXIBLE_290

/* Uncomment the following line if you are using 4.2" tricolor EPD */
//Adafruit_IL0398 display(300, 400, EPD_DC, EPD_RESET, EPD_CS, SRAM_CS, EPD_BUSY);


#define COLOR1 EPD_BLACK
#define COLOR2 EPD_RED


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //while (!Serial) { delay(10); }
  Serial.println("Adafruit EPD test");

  display.begin();

#if defined(FLEXIBLE_213) || defined(FLEXIBLE_290)
  // The flexible displays have different buffers and invert settings!
  display.setBlackBuffer(1, false);
  display.setColorBuffer(1, false);
#endif


  display.clearBuffer();
  for (int i = 0; i< 50; i+=5) {
    display.drawPixel(i,i, COLOR1);
  }
  display.display();
}

void loop() {
  //don't do anything!
}


void testdrawtext(char *text, uint16_t color) {
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  display.setTextColor(color);
  display.setTextWrap(true);
  display.print(text);
}
```

[image: Schematic Diagram]

Comment: A schematic would be nice instead of pictures. It's difficult to see how you have this all hooked up by trying to mentally stitch 3-4 pictures together along with breadboard connections. Please add a schematic.

Comment: Also, the linked E-Ink display is monochrome, but the code you have is for a tri-color display? Are you sure you have the right display choice at the top of your sketch?

Comment: Ron- Ill get a schematic up soon. I've tried the monochrome object but then I usually get no response at all. Not that tricolor is correct, but it causes something to happen. Again, the main issue is inconsistent behavior and I can see changes sometimes with tricolor as opposed to never with monochrome.